# How to write objects to file and retain it even after the program is closed in Java?

Tags: java, swing, object, serialization, deserialization

I am making a Smart ATM project in which a user can create a account as well and thus I will need to store the data to file. I have tried using the Serialization method and writing the objects of User class to the serialized file. But the problem is that whenever I restart the program the database gets re written (Over Written).

I there a way out if this without using any other methods like SQL. I mean I would like to stick with Serialization for now because I am not yet familiar to other methods.

```
public void addUserToDatabase() {
        String fileName = System.getProperty("user.home")+"/accounts.txt";
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            for(int i =0; i<numberOfUser; i++) {
                oos.writeObject(u[i]);
            }
            fos.close();
            oos.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("UNABLE TO ADD USER TO DATABASE!");
        }

    }

    public void fileInputStreamMethod() throws Exception
    {
        String fileName = System.getProperty("user.home")+"/aas.txt";
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);

    int i=12;
    dos.writeInt(i);
    dos.close();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
    int factorial=dis.readInt();
    System.out.println("The No. YOu entered is "+factorial);
    dis.close();
    }
```

Comment: `Serialize` a `Collection` of your values?

Comment: Yes. An array of objects. @ElliottFrisch

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using for loading and storing your collection?

Comment: Basically I need to maintain a database which will hold the objects of User class which includes there account numbers and other things like name.

Comment: Can you please post the code where you are opening and saving data to your file?

Comment: You need a `readFromFile()` method that unserializes the data. Where is your code for that?

Comment: Added the code of the class which stores the database @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: I see that -- but again, where's your code that "un-stores" the database? Without such code, the above code isn't too useful. It is essentially the converse of the storage code, but calls `readObject()` on an [ObjectInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html).

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Added it. @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: Object Serialisation is a really, really bad idea for long term storage of objects.  A single user database would be a preferred option, but you can also use [JAXB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/)

Comment: Will try and use JAXB. @MadProgrammer

Comment: Think of JAXB as text-readable object serialization. Note that just like standard serialization, it won't work for all types and you might have to write some adapter classes to get it to work fully. Also, avoid serializing GUI structural elements and stick to the nucleus of your data model only.

Comment: Is there any other option I can think of. Because I am new to Java. @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: Your options are pretty much deliniated by @MadProgrammer: single user database (best), JAXB (next best), Serialization (so-so), or just writing text out in some proprietary fashion (very fragile and buggy). The most straight forward would be serialization, but it likely isn't the best long-term solution in a production program. Most important, experiment with all and find out what works best for you. The only way to get not-so-new with Java is to push the envelop and write lots and lots of code.

Comment: Thanks for the motivation. I will definitely try and experiment with every method I can. @HovercraftFullOfEels

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your reading to database and writing to database needs to be symmetric -- if you write objects out using an ObjectOutputStream, then to read back, you must read **objects** back in using an ObjectInputStream. You don't do that as you're writing out with the ObjectOutputStream but appear to be reading back in using a DataInputStream. This won't throw an error since everything, even serialized objects, are "data", but your code won't be able to retrieve usable information. If you make your input and outputs symmetric your problem (at least the short term problem) should be solved.

Comment: Will do that. Thanks for the help.